# Switch places on div with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm buildinga site with CSS Media Queries for mobile and I need to switch places on 3 divs.

This is how it looks now : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/3kZW2/

And this is what I need : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/7S7e9/

Is this possible with just changing the css of version 1?

Comment: unless you set `position:` `absolute`  you cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by setting widths on the DIVS and then using float right:

http://jsfiddle.net/wabJn/

Answer (score 0):

Here have a look http://jsfiddle.net/3kZW2/5/

I used absolute positioning. You may need to set the width and positioning as per your need, if div size changes. A more elegant solution would be to move the div2 above div1 in markup, here http://jsfiddle.net/3kZW2/4/